# SQL : remove last comma in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a text memo field in SQL table that I need to remove the last character in the field if it's a comma.

So, for example, if I have these rows, I need to remove the commas from rows 2 and 4.

```
  INETSHORTD
1  94
2  85,
3  94, 92
4  89, 99, 32,
```

The output would be:

```
  INETSHORTD
  94
  85
  94, 92
  89, 99, 32
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you post the out put ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `REVERSE` and `STUFF`:

```
SELECT
    REVERSE(
        STUFF(
            REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(INETSHORTD))), 
            1, 
            CASE WHEN SUBSTRING((REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(INETSHORTD)))), 1, 1) = ',' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
            ''
        )
    )
FROM tbl
```

---

First, you want to `TRIM` your data to get rid of leading and trailing spaces. Then `REVERSE` it and check if the first character is `,`. If it is, remove it, otherwise do nothing. Then `REVERSE` it back again. You can remove the first character by using `STUFF(string, 1, 1, '')`.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/76428/1/0)

Answer (score 15):

Here's a more elegant / readable way:

```
SET @string = REPLACE(@string + '<END>', ',<END>', '')
```

---

if you can't be sure if last comma appear in string, use this:

```
SET @string = REPLACE(REPLACE(@string + '<END>', ',<END>', ''), '<END>', '')
```

Comment: Not elegant or readable IMO. What is <END> and why do we repeat it 3 times?

Answer (score 7):

Use case statement if the particular string is ending with , take the substring with LEFT function and lenght - 1

```
Select
    CASE
        WHEN INETSHORTD LIKE '%,'  THEN LEFT(INETSHORTD, LEN(INETSHORTD)-1)
        ELSE INETSHORTD
    END
From yourtable
```

[example fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40b06/2)

Comment: thanks, but the SHORTD column is a "text, not null" field, so having trouble with LEN: Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of len function.

Comment: this is actually the best answer for normal people who are using varchar etc. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if the syntax was available in 2015 but I would think this is a more elegant solution.

```
SELECT TRIM(',' from INETSHORTD) FROM TABLE
```

Comment: I prefer this to `SELECT
    REVERSE(
        STUFF(
            REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(INETSHORTD))), 
            1, 
            CASE WHEN SUBSTRING((REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(INETSHORTD)))), 1, 1) = ',' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
            ''
        )
    )
FROM tbl`

Comment: It removed every comma from my string (also not great that you can't use it on variables? - I used the Case option by @sachu

Comment: @egmfrs Did you use it as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)? It's very hard to make sense of a comment like that without proper context.

Answer (score 1):

Using CHARINDEX (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) AND LEN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) you should be able to do it like this:

```
SELECT IIF( CHARINDEX( ',', tmp.SHORTD, LEN( tmp.SHORTD ) ) > 0
          , LEFT( tmp.SHORTD, LEN( tmp.SHORTD ) - 1 )
          , tmp.SHORTD )
  FROM tmp
```

This SQL Fiddle shows it at work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a99c8/7.

Comment: thanks, but the SHORTD column is a "text, not null" field, so having trouble with LEN: Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of len function.

Comment: Only because I wanted to prove to myself that my idea could work, you could use SUBSTRING (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and DATALENGTH (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) to get the results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39504e/5

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (id varchar(20)) 
insert into @t(id)values ('94,'),('85,'),('94, 92'),('89, 99, 32,')

SELECT  REVERSE(SUBSTRING(  REVERSE(id),    PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z0-9]%',REVERSE(id)),
    LEN(id) - (PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z0-9]%',REVERSE(id)) - 1)   ) )     
FROM    @t
```