# How to replace a character in a string using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

In my table column, i have below sample data

```
Test1 145,  Area 1
Test2 146,
Test3 145,  Area 2, Plot 10
```

What i want to achieve is to replace "," in the string but only if it is the last character. If i have more characters after "," then the replace should leave the string as it is.

In the example above, the replace would only work in line 2.

The expected out put would be like below

```
Test1 145,  Area 1
Test2 146 
Test3 145,  Area 2, Plot 10
```

In line 2 above, "," has been replaced with empty space.

I have tried this `Replace(column1, ',  ', '') AS ColName` but this replaces all the "," in Test1 and Test3.

Comment: So the 3 lines are a single value or are you showing 3 rows?

Comment: @AlexK. i'm showing 3 rows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL : remove last comma in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420597/sql-remove-last-comma-in-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure IIF isn't available in SQL Server 2005. This is basically the same logic as the previous answer using CASE instead.

```
declare @MyString varchar(50)

set @MyString = 'Test2 146,'

select 
case
    when right(rtrim(@MyString), 1) = ',' then
        substring(@MyString, 1, len(rtrim(@MyString)) - 1)
    else
        @MyString
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(1024) = 'Test2 146,';

SELECT IIF(RIGHT(@value,1) = ',', LEFT(@value, LEN(@value) - 1), @value);
```

For column it looks like below:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [value] VARCHAR(1024)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([value])
VALUES ('Test1 145,  Area 1')
      ,('Test2 146,')
      ,('Test3 145,  Area 2, Plot 10');


SELECT IIF(RIGHT([value],1) = ',', LEFT([value], LEN([value]) - 1), [value])
FROM @DataSource;
```

Comment: looks like `IIF` is only available in 2012+

Comment: You can use `CASE` statement - check the answers below.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this will `LIKE` and `IIF` :

```
SELECT IIF(t.Column LIKE '%,' , LEFT(t.column, LEN(t.column) - 1) , t.column) as new_val
FROM YourTable t
```

**For older versions:** You can use `CASE EXPRESSION` since `IIF` is only available since [2012+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) version(Link by @gotqn)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.Column LIKE '%,' 
            THEN LEFT(t.column, LEN(t.column) - 1) 
            ELSE t.column
       END as new_val
FROM YourTable t
```

Comment: Of course I also just noticed this is tagged 2005 so that won't work for the OP. But it will work for others that stumble in here in the future.

Comment: The `IIF` won't work, but the case will won't it? Or another function here is not available in that version either?

Comment: `CASE` is OK - IIF is from 2012+ editions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx)

Comment: Yes sorry my comment was not very clear. The case expression should work fine. The IIF version should work too but is not likely going to work for the OP as they are on 2005.

Comment: I just tested the case expression but still didn't work, what i have found to be working is the answer by @nscheaffer.

Comment: @StackTrace What do you mean didn't work? what did it do? Maybe you have to use `-2` instead of `-1`? Not sure about SQL-Server `substring`

Comment: @sagi it was not throwing any exception but it didn't remove the `,` in row 2.

Comment: Thats why I said replace `-1` with `-2` @StackTrace

Comment: @sagi Just did another test with -2 instead of -1 but the results are the same, no `,` is replaced. Could it be because its SQL 2005?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN Column1 LIKE '%,' THEN STUFF(column1, LEN(column1), 1, '') 
          ELSE Column1
       END
```

Answer (score 0):

This shows one way to do it.

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(30);

SET @test = 'Test1, 145, Area 1';

SELECT @test;

IF CHARINDEX(',', @test, LEN(RTRIM(@test))) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @test = Replace(@test, ',', '');
END

SELECT @test;

SET @test = 'Test2 146,';

SELECT @test;

IF CHARINDEX(',', @test, LEN(RTRIM(@test))) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @test = Replace(@test, ',', '');
END

SELECT @test;

SET @test = 'Test3 145, Area 2, Plot 10';

SELECT @test;

IF CHARINDEX(',', @test, LEN(RTRIM(@test))) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @test = Replace(@test, ',', '');
END

SELECT @test;
```

-- How to work into a SELECT statement

```
SET @test = 'Test2 146,';

SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', @test, LEN(RTRIM(@test))) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(@test, 1, LEN(@test) - 1) ELSE @test END AS 'Converted Value';
```