# Trim comma off end in XML query with [text()] alias

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following `sql` and I need to trim off the trailing comma (if it exists). I'm an amateur when it comes to `sql` so a little help/guidance would be great.

```
SELECT
    fse.FormSubmissionId,
    CASE
        WHEN fse.Type = 4
            THEN
                (SELECT fse2.FormElementItemText + ', ' as [text()] 
                 FROM dbo.FormSubmissionElement as fse2 
                 WHERE fse2.FormElementId = fse.FormElementId 
                 ORDER BY fse2.FormElementItemText DESC 
                 FOR XML PATH(''))
    END as UserSubmission
```

I've looked around and have found a few ways to trim a comma off the end like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420727/4107391) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420668/4107391). But I'm not sure how to incorporate it into my current `select` statement since the alias is `[text()]` for the `XML`.

I'm sure it's stupid simple but I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the comma at the start instead of at the end you can use [`stuff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to remove it, like this:

```
SELECT
fse.FormSubmissionId,
CASE
    WHEN fse.Type = 4
        THEN
            STUFF((SELECT ', ' +fse2.FormElementItemText as [text()] 
                   FROM dbo.FormSubmissionElement as fse2 
                   WHERE fse2.FormElementId = fse.FormElementId 
                   ORDER BY fse2.FormElementItemText DESC 
                   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
END as UserSubmission
```

The reason is that you know that the string always starts at index 1, but to know what the last index is you have to either do the select twice or use a variable.

Comment: This worked perfectly and thanks for explaining it a bit!

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite it as:

```
SELECT
    fse.FormSubmissionId,
    CASE
       WHEN fse.Type = 4 THEN
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + fse2.FormElementItemText as [text()]-- ', ' goes first
       FROM dbo.FormSubmissionElement as fse2 
       WHERE fse2.FormElementId = fse.FormElementId
       ORDER BY fse2.FormElementItemText DESC 
       FOR XML PATH('')
       ),1,2,'')    -- stuff will remove first 2 characters
END as UserSubmission
...
```