# Remove trailing comma from xml path

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

How do I remove the trailing comma from the result of this query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), clientid) + ','
FROM daily
FOR XML PATH('')
```

The output is `0,0,351,350,`

---

This is not a duplicate. The other questions are not using xml path, but I am.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL : remove last comma in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420597/sql-remove-last-comma-in-string)

Comment: @likwidfire2k I have updated my question to show that it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you use the `FOR XML PATH` query as a sub query and put the comma at the beginning instead of end so that it is easier to `STUFF`:

```
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + CONVERT(varchar(10), clientid)
    FROM daily
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Works in SQL Server

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(10), clientid) + ',', LEN(CONVERT(varchar(10), clientid) + ',') - 1)
  FROM daily
   FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: This does not work because it is removing all commas (Not just the last comma).

Comment: This will only remove the last character of a string... It is not even specifically targeting commas. Example: `SELECT LEFT('0,0,351,350,', LEN('0,0,351,350,') - 1)` returns '0,0,351,350'

Comment: If it is the XML path that is causing this then you will have to put your original query into a subquery then remove the comma.